# Pass click from canvas to iframe behind

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, iframe

I'd like to overlay an iframe with a canvas so I can draw annotations in relation to the iframe's content.

However, I would also like the iframe to function as normal so things like click, scroll, keyboard input etc should pass through the canvas. The canvas *should* handle some events such as click, for instance clicking the yellow square in the example.

Here's just the click event handler which should be all that needs to be corrected.

```
hostCanvas.addEventListener('click', function(event){
    //First, test if entity was clicked.
  var x = event.layerX,
      y = event.layerY;

  var found = false;
  $.each(entities, function(i, entity){
    if (y >= entity.dimensions.y && 
        y <= entity.dimensions.y + entity.dimensions.h && 
        x > entity.dimensions.x && 
        x < entity.dimensions.x + entity.dimensions.w) {
      console.log("entity click detected");
      found = true;
      return;
    }
  });


  if(!found){
    //Otherwise, forward event to element under.
    var under = document.elementFromPoint(event.clientX, event.clientY);

    var evt = new MouseEvent(event.type, {
      view: window,
      bubbles: true,
      cancelable: true,
      screenX: event.screenX,
      screenY: event.screenY,
      clientX: event.clientX,
      clientY: event.clientY,
      ctrlKey: event.ctrlKey,
      shiftKey: event.shiftKey,
      altKey: event.altKey,
      metaKey: event.metaKey,
      button: event.button,
      relatedTarget: event.relatedTarget
    });

    $(hostCanvas).css('pointer-events', 'none');
    console.log("Forwarded event to:");
    console.log(under);
    under.dispatchEvent(evt);
    $(hostCanvas).css('pointer-events', 'auto');
  }

});
```

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/po1zdtz7/5/

Currently, the event appears to be getting sent to the iframe but nothing is happening (no "Got click" alert).

To clarify, expected result is (when clicked):
**Yellow/Orange**: Console says "entity click detected"
**Red**: Should forward click to element behind (iframe, result below) which should then handle the click event.
**iframe (within green border):** Should come up with an alert saying "Got click"

**Update:**
I've done as CBroe commented below:

> Will the iframe always show content from the same domain as in the fiddle example? In that case, I think it might be easier if you do the event handling on the iframe, and only catch and handle what clicks you want to affect the canvas from there.

I've now got it so that the iframe takes the click as normal, passes it to the canvas first which decides if it should handle it or not, if it does, cancel any action in the iframe, otherwise, iframe handles as normal.

Comment: Will the iframe always show content from the same domain as in the fiddle example? In that case, I think it might be easier if you do the event handling on the iframe, and only catch and handle what clicks you want to affect the canvas from there.

Comment: It won't always be from the same domain, though all calls are made through a proxy so injecting scripts into the iframe is possible (if needed). Thanks for the suggestion though, I have an idea on what I could try.

Comment: `I've now got it so that the iframe takes the click as normal, passes it to the canvas first which decides if it should handle it or not, if it does, cancel any action in the iframe, otherwise, iframe handles as normal.` - can you share example ?

Comment: I don't have access to the code anymore. It was likely that I did it so the `iframe` takes the mouse click, passes the event to the canvas' click handler. If the click handler returned `true` then it was handled so then stop handling it in the `iframe` but if it was false, then handle as usual